# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException. Scanner-class

Tags: java

I've looked through some of the questions but I can't seem to find any good solutions.

I have a very simple code that just won't work. It's supposed to get the weight and height of the user, and then compute the BMI.

The values I put in is different everytime.
But lets say 85 for variable vikt and 1.80 for variable langd.
It does work when i use a , instead of a . though.
I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at Labb2.BMI.main(BMI.java:32)
C:\Users\Danne\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

The code I use is the following;

```
package Labb2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner viktObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner langdObj = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double vikt;
        double langd;
        double bmi;

        System.out.print("Ange din vikt: ");
        vikt = viktObj.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Ange din längd i meter (ex. 1.70): ");
        langd = langdObj.nextDouble();

        bmi = vikt / (langd * langd);
        System.out.printf("Ditt BMI är: %.2f", bmi);
        System.out.println("");


    }

}
```

Comment: It works for me. What values did you provide? BTW you don't need two scanners. Use one to read all data from console.

Comment: firstly you don't need two separate scanner objects to read input from the user, one will suffice. The error you are getting is because the number you are inputting is not a double value.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show the input data that caused this exception.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a locale issue? What I mean is, are you using . or , for decimal point? What does your input look like?

Comment: My code does work when I use a , instead of a . acctually.. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

The error can occur in three cases

1) you may be giving a wrong input format(instead of double).  Try to give input in double

2) You may need  useLocale with the scanner class

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

3) You can also use `try-catch` to handle the error by

```
try {
    // ...Your code
} catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
    obj.next();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Input mismatch exception is because your input is of different type than expected input. You can put while loop and check if the input `hasNextDouble()` to make it always work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner viktObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        double vikt;
        double langd;
        double bmi;

        System.out.print("Ange din vikt: ");
        while(!viktObj.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("Wrong input... please enter again!");
            viktObj.next();
        }
        vikt = viktObj.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Ange din längd i meter (ex. 1.70): ");
        while(!viktObj.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("Wrong input... please enter again!");
            viktObj.next();
        }
        langd = viktObj.nextDouble();

        bmi = vikt / (langd * langd);
        System.out.printf("Ditt BMI är: %.2f", bmi);
        System.out.println("");




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason Why You getting error[Exception]**:

When You are required to enter the Double,int and you enter String thn this exception occurs and stops your program.
You can get input with one `Scanner` only you can reuse one `Scanner` again and again no need to make another object of `Scanner`.Like i used

**Note**
Exception Handling not Explained because of beginner level. I recommend to first learn it yourself if problems feel free to ask.
[image: Code i run]

**Example When i getting `InputMismatchException`**

Case when i am getting same error like you.

[image: InputMismatchException]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have entered something not a number. When you use **nextDouble**, that's mean you can only input **numbers, not strings.** I hope this helps. You can use try-catch in order to avoid errors.